# PyQt 4 - How to establish signals between specific, modularly generated widgets

Tags: python, pyqt4

So I have 2 lists of QCheckBoxes driving the state change of each other. Each list resides in a tab, that belongs to a group of tabs, that belongs to a main tab. When I generated the checkboxes, I generated them one tab at a time, and each one gets an unique name. I would like to know if I can check on a specific checkbox in list 1 and have a specific check box's state change in list 2?

Ex. Structure

```
mainTab1 > tab 1 > list 1 checkBox 1-9
         > tab 2 > list 1 checkBox 1-4
         > tab 3 > list 1 checkBox 1-6

mainTab2 > tab 1 > list 2 checkBox 1-3
         > tab 2 > list 2 checkBox 1-11
         > tab 3 > list 2 checkBox 1-8
```

Using this structure, if I check on mainTab1>tab2>list1checkBox3, I want mainTab2>tab1>list2checkBox1 to check on with that change, how should I hook up my signals?

Here's the code that actually generates the tabs and checkboxes

```
    global clusterNames
    global parseByPass
    totalPasses = parseByPass.keys()
    totalPasses.sort()
    cNames = reversed(clusterNames)
    assetCBList, assetNameList, assetPassList, assetROList = [],[],[],[]
    passCBList, passNameList, passPassList, passROList = [],[],[],[]        

    #Create the main window
    self.setFixedSize(900,600)
    self.setWindowTitle("Que Dispatcher")

    #Create all the layouts to be used by main window
    self.windowLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.buttonShelf = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

    #Create the tab widget
    self.tabGroupMain = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
    self.tabGroupMain.setObjectName("tabGroupMain")
    self.tabGroupMain.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10,10,875,530))
    self.tabGroupSub = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
    self.tabGroupSub.setObjectName("tabGroupSub")
    self.tabGroupSub.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10,10,865,520))
    self.tabGroupSub.setStyleSheet("border: 0px")
    self.tabGroupSub2 = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
    self.tabGroupSub2.setObjectName("tabGroupSub2")
    self.tabGroupSub2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10,10,865,520))
    self.tabGroupSub2.setStyleSheet("border: 0px")

    #Create all the tabs and add them to the tab widget
    #Asset tab      
    for index, item in enumerate(cNames):
        currentTab = item + "Tab"
        self.currentTab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.currentTab.setObjectName(currentTab)

        #Create the top line, all control widgets
        self.tabV = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.tabScroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.tabLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.tabLayout.setColumnMinimumWidth(1,175)
        self.tabLayout.setColumnMinimumWidth(2,125)
        self.tabLayout.setRowMinimumHeight(1,15)
        self.allCB = QtGui.QCheckBox()
        self.allCB.setObjectName("%sAllCB" % item)
        self.allNameLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Cluster Name")
        self.allNameLabel.setObjectName("%sAllNameLable" % item)
        self.allPassLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Pass Type")
        self.allPassLabel.setObjectName("%sAllPassLabel" % item)
        self.allRenderOpt = QtGui.QLineEdit("Render Options: Insert Commands")
        self.allRenderOpt.setObjectName("%sAllRenderOpt" % item)

        #Create modullar widgets based on parsed info
        for index, stat in enumerate(QParsed[item][1]):
            statedRO = ""
            assetCB = item  + stat + "CheckBox"
            assetNameLabel = item + stat + "NameLabel"
            assetPassLabel = item + stat + "PassLabel"
            assetRO = item + stat + "ROTF"
            for text in QParsed[item][2][index]:
                statedRO = statedRO + text + " "

            #Add modularly generated widgets with parsed info
            self.assetCB = QtGui.QCheckBox()
            self.assetCB.setObjectName(assetCB)
            self.assetNameLabel = QtGui.QLabel(item)
            self.assetNameLabel.setObjectName(assetNameLabel)
            self.assetPassLabel = QtGui.QLabel(stat)
            self.assetPassLabel.setObjectName(assetPassLabel)
            self.assetRenderOpt = QtGui.QLineEdit(statedRO)
            self.assetRenderOpt.setObjectName(assetRO)

            #Add the all control widgets to a horizontal layout
            self.tabLayout.addWidget(self.allCB,0,0)
            self.tabLayout.addWidget(self.allNameLabel,0,1)
            self.tabLayout.addWidget(self.allPassLabel,0,2)
            self.tabLayout.addWidget(self.allRenderOpt,0,3)

            #Add all modullar widgets
            self.tabLayout.addWidget(self.assetCB, (index+2), 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
            self.tabLayout.addWidget(self.assetNameLabel, (index +2), 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
            self.tabLayout.addWidget(self.assetPassLabel, (index +2), 2, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)    
            self.tabLayout.addWidget(self.assetRenderOpt, (index +2), 3, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        #Add layout to page of current tab widget
        self.tabV.addLayout(self.tabLayout)
        self.tabScroll.setLayout(self.tabV)
        self.tabScroll.setMinimumHeight(850)
        self.tabV.addStretch()
        self.tabGroupSub.addTab(self.tabScroll, item)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is hard to understand. I understand that checking `list1checkBox3` should make `list2checkBox1` checked too. What about unchecking? Should that be synchronized too? And what about the reverse? Should checking/unchecking `list2checkBox1` affect the other one? Moreover, do you have just these 2 checkboxes to be synchronized, or will there be a bunch of checkbox pairs that work together?

Comment: Sorry, I knew this question would be hard to ask since so much needs to happen. So basically, the checkboxes work in pairs. Whatever happens to one needs to happen to the other, so checking and unchecking from both sides. There will be multiple pairs of checkboxes, but only 2 in a group, and there won't be any group to group conversation. So each checkbox only looks to another one, no other.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronizing two checkboxes is pretty easy. You connect the `stateChanged` signal from one to the `setCheckState` method of the other, and vice versa:

```
 checkbox1.stateChanged.connect(checkbox2.setCheckState)
 checkbox2.stateChanged.connect(checkbox1.setCheckState)
```

Now all you need to do is, organize your checkboxes in a suitable container and then connect signals according to your needs. Since you have unique `objectName`s, a `dict` with `objectName` for key and corresponding `QCheckBox` instance as value seems good enough. Then you can have a list of sync pairs. Loop over them and connect signals.

If I understand your code correctly, this is what it should look like (with irrelevant bits snipped to emphasize the logic):

```
# some code snipped here
# ...
self.checkBoxes = {}
# this is just an example
# your real syncPairs should include real names and full list of pairs of course
self.syncPairs = [('list2checkBox1', 'list1checkBox3')] 

for index, item in enumerate(cNames):
    # more code snipped here

    self.allCB = QtGui.QCheckBox()   # I'm not sure about 'self.' part
                                        # You are discarding the old one in the next iteration
                                        # So this will just store the last one in the iteration
                                        # Besides we are going to keep references to all in `self.checkBoxes`
    self.allCB.setObjectName("%sAllCB" % item)

    # here add it to the dict
    self.checkBoxes["%sAllCB" % item] = self.allCB

    # code snipped here

    # btw, you should add these ones to the layout _here_, not in the inner loop. So:
    self.tabLayout.addWidget(self.allCB,0,0)
    self.tabLayout.addWidget(self.allNameLabel,0,1)
    self.tabLayout.addWidget(self.allPassLabel,0,2)
    self.tabLayout.addWidget(self.allRenderOpt,0,3)

    #Create modullar widgets based on parsed info
    for index, stat in enumerate(QParsed[item][1]):
        # code snipped here

        #Add modularly generated widgets with parsed info
        self.assetCB = QtGui.QCheckBox()      # Again, same issue with 'self.'
        self.assetCB.setObjectName(assetCB)

        # add it to the dict
        self.checkBoxes[assetCB] = self.assetCB

        # rest of the code snipped

# after the setup done, we can connect the signals that will keep sync status:
for cb1, cb2 in self.syncPairs:
     self.checkBoxes[cb1].stateChanged.connect(self.checkBoxes[cb2].setCheckState)
     self.checkBoxes[cb2].stateChanged.connect(self.checkBoxes[cb1].setCheckState)
```

**Edit**

A simple demo of two synced checkboxes:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.cb1 = QtGui.QCheckBox('checkbox 1')
        self.cb2 = QtGui.QCheckBox('checkbox 2')

        #self.cb1.stateChanged.connect(self.cb2.setCheckState)
        #self.cb2.stateChanged.connect(self.cb1.setCheckState)

        # alternatively
        self.cb1.toggled.connect(self.cb2.setChecked)
        self.cb2.toggled.connect(self.cb1.setChecked)

        layout.addWidget(self.cb1)
        layout.addWidget(self.cb2)

        self.setWindowTitle('Synced checkboxes')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Dialog()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the logic makes sense to me, but I am running into some issues setting the check state of the second checkbox. I keep on getting either `TypeError: 'setCheckState()' has no overload that is compatible with 'stateChanged(int)'` or `TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'NoneType'`when I tried to use checkbox.setCheckState ...

Comment: @Orchainu: You are sure that you typed `setCheckState`, not `setCheckState()` in the `connect` statement, right?

Comment: @Orchainu: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: So this is what I have, following the logic in the reply:
`cbPairKeys = cbPairs.keys()
 for key in cbPairKeys:
  cbOne = cbPairs[key][0][0]
  cbTwo = cbPairs[key][1][0]
  cbOne.stateChanged.connect(cbTwo.setCheckState)
  cbTwo.stateChanged.connect(cbOne.setCheckState)` and I got the error:
`File "qDis.py", line 478, in __init__
    cbOne.stateChanged.connect(cbTwo.setCheckState)
TypeError: 'setCheckState()' has no overload that is compatible with 'stateChanged(int)'`

Comment: @Orchainu: OK, that's weird. Are you sure `cbTwo` is a regular `QCheckBox` instance? Maybe it's a custom class with overloaded `setCheckState`? Because, `QCheckBox` surely has to have a `setCheckState(int)` method (or more specifically [`setCheckState(Qt::CheckState)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qcheckbox.html#setCheckState) where `Qt::CheckState` is an `int` enum).

Comment: I printed out `cbOne.objectName()` to make sure it is a checkbox, and it is. And yes, `setCheckState(Qt.checkState)` is a valid function in the class and the checkState from `cbOne.checkState()` does return an int. I am not sure why the code keeps throwing this error, because everything lines up.

Comment: @Orchainu: `objectName` doesn't have anything to do with object type. It is just a string that you attach to a `QObject`. Try printing out `type(cbOne)` and `type(cbTwo)`.

Comment: I checked for `objectName()` because I gave each checkbox an unique name with "CB" attachment that tells me that it is a checkbox, and all of them checked out.

Comment: I went ahead and tried `type(cbOne)` anyways and here is what I have `<class 'PyQt4.QtGui.QCheckBox'>`

Comment: @Orchainu: And... Same with `type(cbTwo)`?

Comment: type(cbTwo) had the same result, yes

Comment: @Orchainu: I have added a simple runnable example. Can you try and run it? If it runs as expected, then there is some other issue with your code.

Comment: python sample.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 26, in <module>
    main = Dialog()
  File "sample.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.cb1.stateChanged.connect(self.cb2.setCheckState)
TypeError: 'setCheckState()' has no overload that is compatible with 'stateChanged(int)'

Comment: I am assuming the code runs on your computer? is it maybe the version of python or qt or something?

Comment: @Orchainu: Yes. It is working (as expected). Well, I don't think it's a version issue. If you are using (Py)Qt 4, `setCheckState(int)` should be there (it's there since Qt 4.0). I'd guess, the issue is with your PyQt installation. By the way, I added an alternative way to sync them. You might try that too, if you like.

Comment: hahaha, oh man ... the 2nd method doesn't work either.File "qDis.py", line 478, in __init__
    cbOne.toggled.connect(cbTwo.setCheckState)
TypeError: 'setCheckState()' has no overload that is compatible with 'toggled(bool)'

Comment: @Orchainu: Note that it should be `setChecked` that is connected to `toggled`, not `setCheckState`.

Comment: @Orchainu: Still, that error about `setCheckState` is rather unsettling.